# Is there a Mac app that will open all images within a folder, regardless of the folder depth?

Tags: macos, applications, graphics, folders, filesystem

I have a folder full of additional folders, each of which then contains images. The directory looks something like this:

```
folder0
    folder1
        image1.jpg
        image2.jpg
        image3.jpg
    folder2
        image4.png
        image5.png
        image6.png
        image7.png
```

...and so on. There are about 430 folders within the root one, and I'd estimate ≈20 images (with varying file types) within each subdirectory. Ideally I'd like to be able to browse through all the photos in order, but there doesn't seem to be a high-capacity image browser that can handle that.

The first solution that comes to mind would be to just merge all the folders into one, but the images have to remain in their respective folders.

Is there any app that can do this, or am I just grasping at thin air here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Isn't this where you would want to utilize Smart Folders, and search for Images?

[This tutorial](http://computers.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-use-smart-folders-in-os-x--mac-45896) gives an example, but I've outlined a basic overview below:

> - Open New Smart Folder.
>
> [image: Open New Smart Folder]
>
> - Select the type of search (in this case, type in images, and choose    Kind:Images from the selections.)
>
> [image: Kind: Image]
>
> - Locate the Save button and save the search.
>
> [image: Save]
>
> - Choose a meaningful name for the search. Optionally, check the `Add to Sidebar` box.
>
> [image: Name and Loc]
>
> - Note the presence of the saved Smart Folder search, presuming that you followed the above step.
>
> [image: In Sidebar]

Comment: Answers on Ask Different need to be more than just a link. It's okay to include a link, but please summarize or excerpt it in the answer. The idea is to make the answer stand alone.

Answer (score 1):

You might also just use Spotlight:

[image]

mdfind sorts the files by the containing folder:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemKind=*image' -onlyin /path/to/folder
```

This opens the first 100 images in Preview:

```
mdfind 'kMDItemKind=*image' -onlyin .|sed -n 1,100p|tr \\n \\0|xargs -0 open -a Preview
```

If `kMDItemKind=*image` is missing some file types, try using `kMDItemContentTypeTree=public.image`.